# Visual Studio 2012 runs app with existing errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010

my Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate compiles even though there's an error. It takes the old .exe then. I remember, that there's a popup that asks - "Do you want that we take the old .exe" - or something similar and I probably clicked yes there by mistake. However, I can't find that settings and therefor can't deactivate that.

Does anyone know where I can do that?

Comment: It's in the options. Look somewhere for the build settings. There's an option to abort on error, run the previous successful build or always ask.

Answer (score 5):

Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > Build and Run:

"On Run, when build or deployment errors occur:"
-> "Prompt to launch"

*edit: You may need to click "Show all settings" for the "Projects and Solutions" category to be visible.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This solved my issues, I just couldn't find it. Will mark this answer as "accepted answer" in 9 minutes!